# Defenitions of nested lua modules in ctags

Tags: lua, ctags

I have a question regarding nested lua modules, allow me to
explain:

Let's say I have a lua script called `myscript.lua` and it has a line
like this:

```
local foo = require('foo')
```

This is how `foo/` looks like:

```
foo
├── baz
│   ├── bar.lua
│   └── init.lua
└── init.lua
```

`foo/init.lua` is loaded by the interpreter in the line above. In addition, `foo/init.lua` loads by itself a lot of other files like `foo/bla.lua` and `foo/baz/init.lua` and `foo/baz/bar.lua`. Thus, functions inside `foo/baz/init.lua` and `foo/baz/bar.lua` (e.g `baz.example_function()` and
`bar.other_function()`) are being called in `myscript.lua` like this:

```
foo.baz.example_function()
foo.baz.bar.other_function()
```

The problem is, that when I run `ctags .` I can see in the generated `tags` file has entries like:

```
baz.example_function    foo/baz/init.lua    /^function baz.example_function()$/;"   f
bar.other_function  foo/baz/bar.lua /^function bar.other_function()$/;" f
```

While I edit `myscript.lua` and my cursor is positioned on
`foo.baz.example_function()`, I want to jump to the definition of
`baz.example_function()` which is located in the file
`foo/baz/init.lua`, my text editor is telling me it can't find it.

I understand why it can't find the definition -- because the correct
definition in the `tags` file is for `baz.example_function` -- without
the preceding `foo.`. If I manually add the preceding `foo.` to the
definition I can easily jump to `foo/baz/init.lua`.

**My question is this:** How do I tell `ctags` to write this preceding
`foo.` automatically in the `tags` file? I have a lot of functions like these I would like to be able to jump to their definitions this way.

Help will be much appreciated, thanks.